# PHP: change if/else to one line conditional fails. I'd like to know why

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have a working **if/else** on a SQL return. If it's empty I display a default.

```
<?php 
if($row['imagename']==='')
    {
        echo "placeholder.png";
    }
else 
    {
         echo htmlspecialchars($row['imagename'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    } ?>
```

and I tried to put it all on one line i.e.

```
<?php ($row['imagename']==='') ? echo "placeholder.png";:echo htmlspecialchars($row['imagename'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>
```

which fails.

Could someone clarify why it fails?

tia

Comment: @Yan is right, there is a typo.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Remove the semicolon and add the `echo` at the beginning.

```
<?php echo ($row['imagename']==='') ? "placeholder.png" : 
      htmlspecialchars($row['imagename'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>
```

Answer (score 6):

```
<?php echo ($row['imagename']==='') ? "placeholder.png" : htmlspecialchars($row['imagename'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>
```

You are using the ternary operator incorrectly

Answer (score 5):

As a language construct, `echo` doesn't like to be in a `?:` expression. Do this instead:

```
echo true ? 'foo' : 'bar';
```

Comment: ?? according to **vld** (at least at PHP version 5.3.10), the compiler emits exactly what I would expect and the same as `echo (true ? 'foo' : 'bar');`

Comment: @TerryE ?? I do not understand what you're saying. "vld"? I'm saying `true ? echo 'foo' : echo 'bar';` does not work, which it doesn't on 5.3.13.

Comment: Sorry deceze, I misread your A. My bad and mindfart.  +1 on yr ans. echo is a statement and not a function.  BTW for other readers [vld](http://pecl.php.net/package/vld) is an opcode disassembler.

Answer (score 2):

It fails because it's meant to be used with expressions and not statements.
Refer to [php comparison operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)  under ternary operator.

By putting a `;` at the end of your expressions you have made them into statements.

Refer to: [Expressions and statements](http://www.vanguardsw.com/dphelp4/dph00238.htm) to understand the difference between the two.

Answer (score 1):

One difference between print and echo is that print has a value, while echo does not.

The construct:

```
$test ? planA : planB
```

chooses one of the values planA or planB, even if you no intention of using the result. Since echo has no value, it won’t work:

```
$test ? echo 'plan A' : echo 'plan B'; // <-- not working
```

If you want to use this simple syntax, just replace your echo statements with print statements.

```
$test ? print 'plan A' : print 'plan B'; // <-- should work
```